# c++0x multithreading memory visibility without atomic operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, atomic

The common pattern for synchronizing data between threads (besides using spinlock) with atomics is like this:

```
int data;
std::atomic<bool> ready;

void thread1()
{
   data = 123;
   ready.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}
void thread2()
{
   while(!ready.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
   int theData = data;
   assert(theData == 123);
}
```

or better:

```
void thread2()
{
   while(!ready.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
   std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
   int theData = data;
   assert(theData == 123);
}
```

The 'ready' flag is used to 1) determinate when data is indeed ready, and 2) for happends-before relationship.

But if I somehow know (potentionally not by using c++ atomics) that data will be ready when I read it , then can I omit this kind of flag?

Could I use this:

```
int data = 0;
void thread1()
{
   sleep(1000);
   data = 123;
   std::atomic_thread_fence(some_order);
}
void thread2()
{
   sleep(2000);
   std::atomic_thread_fence(some_order);
   int theData = data;
   assert(theData == 123);
}
```

or

```
std::atomic<int> atmData(0);
void thread1()
{
   sleep(1000);
   atmData.store(123, some_order);
}
void thread2()
{
   sleep(2000);
   int theData = atmData.load(some_order);
   assert(theData == 123);
}
```

And if so, what some_order would then could be?
I'm not sure this would be possible since even with `std::memory_order_seq_cst` ordering operations can still see stale value. On other hand `std::atomic_thread_fence()` seem to require atomic operation to work (according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence).

EDIT: It's rather theoretical question about how memory synchronization works in c++ and not about how should I use waiting mechanisms or know when it's safe to access the data.

Comment: Whoever proclaimed that this is a "standard pattern" of some kind, was deeply wrong. There is no "standard pattern" of any kind for synchronizing threads, and, in fact, mutexes and condition variables are used far more often than atomics.

Comment: I keep wanting to give you my answer (yes, of course, sure), but then I have to ask ... do you think you know how to achieve that confidence that the data is 'ready'?

Comment: Unless you write/read atmData very frequently from multiple threads, having a simple mutex pattern would be more readable, maybe. Also why are you sasying "spin wait" is standard? Isn't it slower than events, callbacks or waiting/awaking?

Comment: @2785528 I could, for example, make such check from another language that is invoking methods in c++ (and this is my intention btw.)

Comment: Common pattern of synchronizing data between named threads is multiple producers and single consumer queue for each thread. Like you do you either  sleep when the data was ready for consumption or are busy-waiting for it to become ready, both being bad.

Comment: Presumably, that other language would issue all the necessary memory barriers and synchronization (otherwise, I don't see how you can "make such check" from it) - in which case, you would not have concurrent access on the C++ side, and the issue would fail to arise.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, Presumably. But I don't think it's safe to rely on mix of memory models and order constrains of various languages. The situation would be like this: in c++ I have two methods: init() and consume(). init() must be called first; after it's fully executed it's safe to call consume(). These two methods would be called from other language (and from diffrent threads) which would need to ensure when its safe to call consume(), probably using its own constructs like conditional variables or atomics.

Comment: If you are asking whether the C++ standard provides some kind of guarantee that it's safe to call `consume` after `init` from another language if that language ensures sufficient synchronization, then of course the C++ standard provides no such guarantee, for the simple reason that it doesn't at all contemplate a program assembled from pieces written in different languages. A behavior of such a program is implementation-defined, so you would need to consult your particular implementation. If you are asking something else, it would help if you were to explicitly state the question.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, So then, I would have to introduce synchronization in the c++ code too. I could do this with mutex (but I won't becouse consume() will be executed from many threads) and I could do this with conditional variables (which would have no sence since there is no 'condition', consume() it's guaranteed to be called after init()) and I could this with atomics like at the top on my question (which is ok, but there is still no purpose for the 'ready' flag, it has to be ready already). ....

Comment: ... So I would like to have it done with something like memory fence, but it does not seem to work without atomic operation like I wrote at the end of the question.

Comment: *"I would have to introduce synchronization in the c++ code"* contradicts *"`consume()` is guaranteed to be called after `init()`"* If you are concerned that the memory models of the two languages are different and incompatible, what does "called after" mean here, and how and by whom is it guaranteed? If on the other hand you feel that the memory models of the two languages are sufficiently compatible that the other language can guarantee the "called after" property for the C++ parts (known as "happens-after" in C++ parlance), then you don't need any additional synchronization on the C++ side.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, By called after I mean only that the caller code calls the init() (once). When it knows the init() has complited (e.g. it returned control to the caller), then it may call consume() (multiple times, from diffrent threads). So by after or before I mean only the time, not any happens-befor or anything related to the memory model or synchronisation.

Comment: Again - if you believe that this sequence of events is as good as the C++'s happens-after guarantee, then you don't need any synchronization on the C++ side. If you suspect it's weaker than happens-after, then you have to treat `init` and `consume` calls as not externally synchronized, and provide internal synchronization as necessary. Examine the memory model of that other language to decide which assumption you want to labor under. Your confusion arises out of trying to have it both ways.

Comment: I would just go with the seemingly redundant "ready" flag + spinlock. It's not useless; its purpose is to guarantee inter-thread synchronization. For this type of spinlock, you won't see any performance hit, because you're spinning on read with a non-contended write. It will be amortized lightning-fast. If it truly is not needed, it will never even spin. Then you don't need to worry about if the memory models are compatible. That's a big development win with almost zero performance cost.